# How to make notepad++ function like regular notepad in cmd?

Tags: java, cmd, notepad++

I like using the command prompt to write and compile java.
To write the code I enter this in cmd:

notepad MyJavaClass.java

This opens notepad and asks if I want to create new file (If it doesn't already exist).
The problem for me is that I like using notepad++ as a text editor because it has nice features.

So my question is:

**How do I make it so that I can type "notepad++ MyJavaClass.java" in cmd and have notepad++ open up, ready for editing without having to type the full path of notepad++?**

I tried to simply place the notepad++.exe file in the System32 folder, but cmd 
doesn't recognize the command.

Sorry for the noobiness :)

Comment: This might be better suited for SuperUser as it is how to get NP++ to work rather than a specific programming question. It is however a good question.

Comment: It is bad practise to drop exe in the OS's folder. Better edit the `path` value of environment variable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add notepad++ to your `path`

**In Windows (Using GUI):**

From the Start Menu, right-click Computer, select Advanced system settings in the left area, then select Environment Variables at the bottom in the window that pops up.

Go to the PATH user variable and click edit, and append YOUR path to notepad++ to the end. 
For example:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++;`

Don't forget the semi-colon! Be sure the entry before it is also ended with a semi-colon.

**In Windows (Using command line running as Administrator)**

To set only for the duration of command line session:

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++;`

To permanently set, use the same command as above but replace `set` with `setx`:

Note that not all Windows distributions come with setx, and can be manually installed [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18546).

Comment: Thank you! Do you know a good guide about environment variables to suggest before I go looking?

Comment: I can't think of anything off the top of my head, there should plenty of good information out there though:)

Answer (score 26):

Notepad++ is a known app, so if you launch it with the `START` builtin, it'll work without having to modify the `PATH`.

```
start notepad++ MyJava.java
```

Answer (score 4):

Sidestepping the question slightly, I made a Windows batch file to give command-line access to Notepad++. Rather than add to the PATH pigpile, I put an `npp.bat` file in a tools directory that is already in the path.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %*
```

Then from any command line:

```
npp foo.java
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
Autorun 
path %userprofile%\desktop;%path%&doskey /macrofile="%userprofile%\macros.txt"
```

Here I'm adding a path, then setting the doskey macros.

You could do this

```
doskey /macrofile="%userprofile%\macros.txt"
```

In the macros.txt do this

```
n="c:\somewhere\notepad++.exe" $*
```

Now you just type

```
n <filename>
```

See

```
set /?
doskey /?
cmd /?
```