# how to open an app with a shortcut (like only the name of the app) using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, shortcut

I want to do something that whenever I write the word "notepad++" in my PowerShell, the Notepad++ app will be opened (I know if I set alias, I can open notepad++ in the PowerShell, but I want the Notepad++ app be opened outside of PowerShell)
Is that even possible? how? I want it to be permanent so every time I open PowerShell, I could easily open notepad++ with it
this is what I did and the app will open in the PowerShell:

```
cd $env:USERPROFILE\Documents
md WindowsPowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
cd WindowsPowerShell
New-Item Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 -ItemType "file" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
powershell_ise.exe .\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
#and then in the ise that is open I wrote:
Set-Alias notepad++ C:\ProgramFiles\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
```

Comment: Here's a guide on [PowerShell profile's](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/)

Comment: Most appropriate way would be to set an environment variable imo

Comment: how can I set an environment variable imo?

Comment: @Arghavanvg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107723/how-to-make-notepad-function-like-regular-notepad-in-cmd